# Javascript Date Output

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to output dates in `dd/mm/yyyy` format? I need it in this short format to make it compatible with my database.

```js
var date = new Date();

// add 8 months
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);

document.getElementById('theDate').value = date;

// check if it is a saturday
if(date.getDay() == 6)
{
  // if it is then add two days
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2);
}

if(date.getDay() == 0)
{
  // if it is then add one days
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
}

document.getElementById('theDate').value = date;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="theDate" name="taksittarih1" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Comment: add 8 months. Code: adds 1 month. Seems legit.

Comment: i am sorry about it i fix to comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some string manipulation for the format conversion, I am assuming you don't want to use jQuery:

```js
var date = new Date();

// add 8 months
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);

document.getElementById('theDate').value = date;

// check if it is a saturday
if(date.getDay() == 6)
{
  // if it is then add two days
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2);
}

if(date.getDay() == 0)
{
  // if it is then add two days
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
}
var dateString = ("0" + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + (date.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) +"/"+ date.getUTCFullYear();
document.getElementById('theDate').value = dateString;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="theDate" name="taksittarih1" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot thats the answer

Comment: do you have any idea how can i change input type ="text" to input type="date" ?

Comment: @kenansalim Use `valueAsDate`, like in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4zxjet8u/

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [JavaScript Date Format library](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

```
var now = new Date();

now.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
```